# Populating values into dropdown from jquery onchange of another dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am having two dropdowns in my page.On change of my first dropdown i need to populate the array values into another dropdown.On every change it should change the values.Can u please help on this

Comment: See this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170453/display-dropdown-values-based-on-previous-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

try following :

```
  $("#dropDown1").change(function(){
        var dp2Values = [1,2,3,4,5];
        $("option",$(this)).remove();
        $.each(dp2Values ,function(a,b){
             $("<option></option>").text(b).appendTo($("#dropDown2"));
        });
    });
```

if you'r data would depend on selected index use this to retrive index :

```
 $("#dropDown1").change(function(){
            var $index = $("option:selected",$(this));            
        });
```

Comment: Thanks very much.But when i am changing second time the values are coming twice....I want only once on every change...can u please help on this

Comment: updated the code.added this line : $("option",$(this)).remove();

Comment: @user1799494 it is a good habit to accept the answer if it solve your problem!