# How to get the value of Select without using submit(either post or get)

Tags: php, wordpress, web

```
<select name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" name="sortbox">
    <option value="" disabled>Sort by</option>
    <?php
        $categories = get_categories(['exclude' => 1]);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo "<option>$category->name </option>";
        }
    ?>
    <option>Newest</option>
    <option>Oldest</option>
    <option>Title Asc</option>
    <option>Title Desc</option>
</select>
```

And I want to get the value of the selected option without redirecting or using form, for me to use it in function.

How can I do that?

Comment: You will have to use javascript. php is a server side programming language and does not know what the visitor is doing on your website.

Comment: sadly that wont work cause im using javascript in a function

Comment: var result = "<?php myFunction() ?>";
 document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = result;
 initAudio($('#playlist li:first'));

Comment: exactly this code

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153595/getting-the-option-value-without-submitting-a-form.

Comment: use javascript , if you need to manipulate data on the server use AJAX solutions.

Comment: "sadly that wont work cause im using javascript in a function" - What do you mean? Do you want to "get" the value for the browser or the server? If server side, there is no way for PHP to reach into a page and grab a value. You'll need to use Javascript in the browser and AJAX to post it to a PHP script.